# User defined functions in zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt, version-control

I'm trying to use a functions that returns the number of commits in a given branch in the zsh prompt. This is what I have now:

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
autoload -Uz vcs_info
precmd() { vcs_info }
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b $(commits %b)'
commits() { git rev-list --count "$1" 2>/dev/null }
PROMPT='${vcs_info_msg_0_} > '
```

which results in

```
master $(commits master) >
```

instead of, for example

```
master 80 >
```

so the `commits` function doesn't get evaluated. How can I fix this?

Comment: Doesn't work, I get the error: `VCS_INFO_formats:fg:50: job not found: b` (50 is the line in my `.zshrc` where `zstyle ...` is)

Comment: Indeed, try setting the prompt from `precmd` and set the `PROMPT_SUBST` option: `setopt prompt_subst; precmd(){ vcs_info; PROMPT="${vcs_info_msg_0_} > " }` (untested).

Comment: Oh, the solution was simply to replace single quotes `'` with double quotes.

Comment: That means that you had the `prompt_subst` option already set. Is it the default now?

Comment: I had it set all along, it's the first line in the code I posted.

Comment: sorry, didn't notice it ;-)